# Subgraph extracting based on nodes

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I am trying to find what are the approaches for extracting a subgraph basing on nodes..
We've got a big graph ( directed or not ) and we've got a list of nodes which we want to extract from graphs but we want to extract also intermediate nodes...

When we look at subgraph extraction based on 2 nodes, problem is very easy... we can decide between extracting all the intermediate nodes in all simply paths between those 2 nodes, or only intermediate nodes from shortest path...

but what if there are more than 2 nodes to extract... How can one deal with that problem?

I am struggling to find any publications about such a problem... probably because i don't know what is its exact name. ( if it really appears in graph theory problems )

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want the smallest subtree that spans a set of vertices?

Comment: Question that you've asked me solved my problem ( different point of view )  :) I've found the problem name - Steiner tree finding... thx Jan :)

Answer (score 0):

As Jan commented, question isn't specific what a goal is.

If you want to minimize tree weight problem is called [generalized Steiner tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree#Generalization_of_minimum_Steiner_tree).

If you want any kind of spanning tree between these nodes, you can make minimum spanning tree on graph with set of nodes you want to connect and edges that connect each pair of nodes with a shortest path between them. That is a complete graph, which is expensive to create. I think it is possible to speed it up by spreading from each node simultaneously and when two 'bubbles' touch first time create path (same shortest) between these 2 points. Incrementally all nodes will be connected. Probably some of path overlap, which can be used to shorten the tree.